# Apollo smart query data not updating when variable is changed (Shopify Storefront API + Nuxt + Vuex + Apollo + GraphQL)

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, shopify-storefront-api

After days crawling through documentation I am unable to get past this issue.

I am building a currency toggle which will allow customers to switch between $AUD and $USD currencies in the UI. I am attempting to implement this via Shopify's Storefront API [International Pricing GraphQL](https://shopify.dev/custom-storefronts/products/international-pricing) queries, specifically the [@inContext directive](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/reference/directives/incontext).

I'm storing a `countryCode` variable in the Vuex store (which is updated via a toggle in the UI) and passing it into an Apollo Smart Query as a reactive variable in the page component.

I am able to successfully retrieve product data/prices for a certain country on first load but my issue is when updating the `countryCode` Smart Query variable via a Vuex action it has no effect on the Apollo data even though the Vuex data updates as desired.

I'm not sure if this issue is directly related to the Shopify Storefront API or a mistake with my Apollo query?

FYI – when updating the reactive variable `productHandle`, the data automatically updates as expected.

#### Page template

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    productHandle: "product-name",
  }),

  // Get selected country code from Vuex store module
  computed: {
    currentCountryCode() {
      return this.$store.getters["currency/countryCode"];
    },
  },

  // Pass country code to Smart query variable
  apollo: {
    product: {
      client: "shopify",
      query: ProductByHandle,
      variables: function () {
        return {
          handle: this.productHandle,
          countryCode: this.currentCountryCode, // this should be reactive but doesn't effect query when variable is updated/changes
        };
      },
      update(data) {
        return _get(data, "productByHandle", {});
      },
      deep: true, // has no noticeable effect 
    },
  },
}
```

#### GraphQL query (for context)

```js
query ProductByHandle($handle: String!, $countryCode: CountryCode!) @inContext(country: $countryCode) {
    productByHandle(handle: $handle) {
        id
        title
        handle
        productType
        tags
        description
        descriptionHtml
        availableForSale
        vendor
        images(first: 10) {
            edges {
                node {
                    transformedSrc
                }
            }
        }
        priceRange {
            minVariantPrice{
              amount
              currencyCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've been finding that I have to set `fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'` on the Apollo query if I'm passing the `product` data to a component. If you're using the `product` data where the Apollo Query happens (i.e. same component / page ), you can skip the `fetchPolicy` and just add the watcher.

```
apollo: {
  product: {
    client: "shopify",
    query: ProductByHandle,
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    variables: function () {
      return {
        handle: this.productHandle,
        countryCode: this.currentCountryCode
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next, I've been using a watcher and call a method to update the pricing. For example:

```
methods: {
  updatePrice(product) {
    this.minPrice = Number(product.node.priceRange.minVariantPrice.amount).toFixed(2),
    this.maxPrice = Number(product.node.priceRange.maxVariantPrice.amount).toFixed(2),
    this.compareAtMinPrice = Number(product.node.compareAtPriceRange.minVariantPrice.amount).toFixed(2),
    this.compareAtMaxPrice = Number(product.node.compareAtPriceRange.maxVariantPrice.amount).toFixed(2)
  }
},
watch: {
  product: function(newval, oldval) {
       this.updatePrice(newval)
    }
  }
```

This works, but I'd love to figure out a solution that includes having caching. I suspect using a mutation when the currency changes might do it, but haven't dug into it.